# Comma Before Things Like "I thought"?

Tags: grammar

Would it be okay to write or say a sentence like this, and would it be grammatically correct?

Examples:

- He went to Aruba, I thought.
- You're wrong, I think.
- These look like deer tracks, I would say.
- He was mad, it seemed.

I know that you typically wouldn't write a sentence like this, but I find myself speaking like this sometimes, and I'm wondering if it's not okay to say or write it like this.

Thank you

Comment: The problem is that you didn’t notice, one typically *would* write a sentence like that. What made you think otherwise?

It’s good whenever you find yourself speaking like that.

More usefully, please consider the difference between “I’m wondering if it's not OK…” and “I’m wondering if it's OK…”

Both work grammatically but in English idiom, no-one would use “if it's not…” except to make specific distinction against “if it is…”.

It would it be OK to write or say a sentence like that, and it would be grammatically correct.

Comment: A teacher of mine marked me down for writing a sentence similar to those sentences, so I just came here to ask if I was right.

Comment: Put a period there, he said.

Comment: Jolly good. What does that change, please?

Comment: I put something along the lines of "He's sad, it seems." When I went up to him to defend my answer, he said it's an independent clause or some crock of crap like that, so it should have a period. I said that it's sort of like an afterthought, so it should be a comma. He raised his voice after that, so I just reluctantly accepted his judgement.

Comment: Can you post the sentence “similar to those” or must we guess? There’s nothing wrong with "He's sad, it seems”, I suggest - but who knows what “something along the lines of…” really was?

Crock of crap or not, where was he suggesting you put your periods? Are you suggesting “He went to Aruba. I thought.” Or what?

Might you be be better off using your original words, and taking them to English Language Learners?

Comment: I wrote, "Albert speaks as much as he likes, it seems." Sorry. Didn't want to compromise my identity or something.

Comment: Why not take that somewhere such as ELL?

Comment: I've had question answered here before, so I just decided it was okay to post my questions on English usage in English Language and Usage.